# Get the last time before the call - SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have here a set of 2 tables that I need to bash.
First table is the list of time and date the customer contacted us, its not unique.
The next table is the escalated call they made to us.

What I need to do is to show the date and time before the escalated call.

I can do simple left join based on customer ID, but having issue on the getting the last call.
Hope that I can get answers + explanation that I can use moving forward.

Here's my code so far:

```
Select a.customer id, a.contact_time, b.date of contact time as last_contact
from escalated_call a
left join all calls b on a.customer id = b.customer ID
```

[image]

Comment: Note that most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images. Also show us your current query attempt. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: hi, i am using SQL... oracle for the tool. Apologies but I am not sure on how to attach a sample data which I have prepared as well so i pasted an image.

Comment: here's my code so far: `Select a.customer id, a.contact_time, b.date of contact time as last_contact
from escalated_call a 
left join all calls b on a.customer id = b.customer ID`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help will give you editing tips. But it's actually quite easy, just type the data in proper columns, highlight and click `{}`.

Comment: Tip: Chose table aliases that make sense, e.g. `ec` for `escalated_calls`.

Comment: thanks for this, this is noted moving forward

Answer (score 0):

Just Use a Where Clause

```
Select  a.customerid, 
        a.contact_time, 
        b.DateOfContactTime as last_contact
from    escalated_call AS a LEFT JOIN Calls AS b on a.customerID = b.customerID
WHERE   a.contact_time < b.DateOfContactTime
```

Comment: hi, need to show the last contact time prior to the escalated call, this show all the prior calls...

Answer (score 0):

You just need an aggregate max here, you can also do it with a correlated subquery but it’s probably not worth it.

You may need to correct your column names, I’ve just guessed you have underscored instead of the spaces

```
Select a.customer_id
      ,a.contact_time
      ,max(b.date_of_contact_time) as last_contact
from escalated_call a
left join all_calls b 
  on a.customer_id = b.customer_ID 
Group by a.customer_id, a.contact_time
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join and return the `FIRST ROW ONLY`:

```sql
SELECT ec.*, ac.dt
FROM   escalated_calls ec
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT ac.dt
         FROM   all_calls ac
         WHERE  ac.customer_id = ec.customer_id
         AND    ac.dt <= ec.ct
         ORDER BY ac.dt DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) ac
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE all_calls(customer_id, dt) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '00:35' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '01:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '00:15' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '00:35' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '01:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE escalated_calls (customer_id, ct) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '00:45' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-12-24' + INTERVAL '00:05' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMER_ID | CT | DT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2019-12-24 00:45:00 | 2019-12-24 00:35:00 |
> | 2 | 2019-12-24 00:05:00 | 2019-12-24 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9c3753a2166b40ce2bc7fbe7dfbe1813)*

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a subquery in the select clause to solve this problem.

```sql
SELECT e.*
, ( SELECT max(a.Date_Of_Contact_Time) 
      FROM all_calls a 
       WHERE a.customer_id = e.customer_id 
        AND a.Date_Of_Contact_Time <= e.contact_time  
   ) AS correct_answer
FROM escalated_calls e
;
```